# iOS Render to Texture: Why it is Clear

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

I'm trying to offscreen render using this post 
http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-1785-post-54500.html#pid54500

First I init FBO.

```
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0,  GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES); 
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) { 
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Then I draw to my texture

```
GLint oldFBO, oldViewPort[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, &oldFBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, oldViewPort);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, listFrameBuffers[i]);
glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// draw code here
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, oldFBO);
glViewport(oldViewPort[0], oldViewPort[1], oldViewPort[2], oldViewPort[3]);
```

And then each frame I draw it.

**When I finish my frame calling glSwapBuffers texture attached to framebuffer becomes clear**
(but when I draw to frame buffer each time after glSwapBuffers everything is ok).

Comment: Where does glSwapBuffers come into this? It's not in the above code you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I mean flushing frame to the screen

Answer (score 0):

So, the quest is completed.
I just changed draw code to this

```
GLint oldFBO, oldViewPort[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, &oldFBO);
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, oldViewPort);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, listFrameBuffers[i]);
glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
//glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // HERE
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // AND HERE

// draw code here

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, oldFBO);
glViewport(oldViewPort[0], oldViewPort[1], oldViewPort[2], oldViewPort[3]);
```

and it works! :)